# How can I access all keys and values in an array of objects without looping

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, d3.js, data-visualization

I am working on a data visualization project, where I parsed every article on the frontpage of a particular news website, searching for 10 distinct words. Then I counted every occurrence of that word for that particular day.

I am trying to implement a line graph to display the usage of each word over time. What I want to do, is have a button exist for each word, and upon clicked, display a line graph corresponding to the data set of each word.

My 1st problem is that all this data is stored in on large dataset. No problem, I have formatted the data to now exist in one large object, with 10 keys for each word. Each of these keys contain an array in the value pair. This array contains objects with (date, and word_count) key and values respectively.

However, the [example](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_change_data.html) I am using to model my project off of uses a completely different data set, and is able to access the data different, so now problems arise.

Here is my newly formatted data, all existing in one object. This is the only way I found I was able to separate each word into it's own dataset. The words like "Extremist", "God", "Guns", etc. are the keys.

[image]

The values is an array of objects containing the (date and count) key, value pairs respectively

[image]

**PROBLEM**

This object exists in a variable called "data_count"

What I need to be able to do, similar to what the example states, is access all date and count variables with this syntax: `data_count.Obama.date` or `data_count.Obama.count`

Right now, to access all date or count values, I need to loop through them and access each index of the "Obama" array like so

```
data_count.Obama[i].date
```

The issue is, I need to insert these date and column values to be accepted as the "x" and "y" coordinates using the d3.line function. So I can't loop through them. As you can see in the example, the user accesses his key value pairs through simple dot notation. But when I replicate his process, the value appears as undefined.

Sorry for the wall of text! Hopefully someone can help me out! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I believe you are over complicating the question: your data is very compatible, with the update function in the example you shared. You have data arrays just like the example, each item in the arrays represents a point on the line having properties representing both x and y values. The update function can be passed your data or the examples data with minor tweaks to account for the x axis being a date instead of a number:

You don't need to do anything differently beyond basic modifications: changing the scale to take a date, changing the extent of the x axis so that the min doesn't equal 0, change the properties passed to each scale, etc. Once you do that you can pass any property of `current_data` to your update function.

```js
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nickrinaldi88/BreitBart_DataVis/main/breitbartData.csv").then(function(csv) {
  
  var current_data = {};
  var parse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")
  
  for(var i=0; i < csv.length; i++) {
    var item = csv[i];
    if(!current_data[item.Word]) current_data[item.Word] = [];
         
    current_data[item.Word].push({
      date:parse(item.Date),
      count:item.Count
    })
  }
  
d3.select("select")
  .selectAll("option")
  .data(Object.keys(current_data))
  .enter()
  .append("option")
  .text(function(d) { return d; });
  
d3.select("select")
  .on("change", function() {
    update(current_data[this.value])
  })
  
  
  
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Initialise a X axis:
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0,width]);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .attr("class","myXaxis")

// Initialize an Y axis
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class","myYaxis")

// Create a function that takes a dataset as input and update the plot:
function update(data) {

  // Create the X axis:
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date }) );
  svg.selectAll(".myXaxis").transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .call(xAxis);

  // create the Y axis
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.count  }) ]);
  svg.selectAll(".myYaxis")
    .transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .call(yAxis);

  // Create a update selection: bind to the new data
  var u = svg.selectAll(".lineTest")
    .data([data]);

  // Updata the line
  u
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class","lineTest")
    .merge(u)
    .transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .attr("d", d3.line()
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .y(function(d) { return y(d.count); }))
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-width", 2.5)
}

// At the beginning, I run the update function on the first dataset:
update(current_data.Obama)

 

})
```

```css
path {
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<select></select>
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, I appreciate it. This code seems to have solved all my problems. I was definitely overthinking it. This was my first real dabble in d3, so I'm gonna compare this code with what I had previous to see what is different, and why it wasn't working why I wanted.

Comment: Hey, would you be able to explain something? In the update function, when we add the "d" attribute and pass in d3.line as the second argument, we return x(d.date) and y(d.count). If I try to console.log(d.date) or d.count, I receive undefined. That is why I didn't think we could access those columns, so I was thinking of another way. The "d" argument represents our data, correct? So if I console log the data, which is current_data, pass in the word selected via dropdown, current_data["Obama"], then try to access all the date columns via current_data["Obama"].date, why do I receive "undefined"?

Comment: You should be able to log d.date wherever d.date is used in the snippet above: `.x(function(d) { console.log(d.date); return x(d.date); })` will log the dates on that line. You have to do it in the inline function because here `d` represents a point in the line and the function is iterated over every point. `d` is passed as a parameter to the inline function automatically by d3 behind the scenes and won't be defined elsewhere. But perhaps I'm not understanding.

Comment: Also, you *should* get undefined with `current_data["Obama"].date` as `current_data["Obama"]` is an array with no property `date`, instead you could log `current_data["Obama"][0].date` or, within the update function `data[0].date`.